# necessary and sufficient condition for Normalization of Integral schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:Y \longrightarrow X$ be a morphism of integral schemes. I was wondering if the following is true?

$f$ is the normalization morphism $\Leftrightarrow$ $Y$ is normal and $f$ is birational and integral.

I know that the direct sense ''$\Rightarrow$" hold, but I don't really see it for the other implication, can anyone clarify if it does hold? or how?

Thanks.

Comment: You use the word integral in two different ways. 1) integral schemes; 2) $f$ is integral. Care to explain what you mean by (I have a good guess) the second?

Comment: Oh yes, of course: in the second, I mean that $f$ is affine and for each open $U=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ the map $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_Y) \longrightarrow \Gamma(f^{-1}(U), \mathcal{O}_X)$ is an integral ring extension

Comment: The reverse implication is correct (at least for Noetherian schemes) and I suggest just apply the definitions to get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This result is true. Let $Q(R)$ denote the fraction field of a domain $R$.

We'd like to show that $f:Y\to X$ is the same as the normalization. It suffices to do this locally on $Y$ if we can do it in a compatible manner. Since $f$ is affine by definition of an integral morphism, we can cover $Y$ by open affines which are the preimage of open affines in $X$, say $V=\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A=U$  where $U\subset X$ and $V\subset Y$ are open affines. Since birational morphisms are dominant, we have that the generic point of $V$ maps to the generic point of $U$ and thus an injective map on fraction fields $Q(A)\to Q(B)$ which by birationality is an isomorphism. Further, $A\subset Q(A)$ lands in $B\subset Q(B)$ under this morphism, and so the integral closure of $A$ is contained in the integral closure of $B$. But $B$ is integrally closed and an integral extension of $A$ by the assumption that $f$ is integral, and this is exactly the manner in which we construct the normalization, so we're done.

This result can be shown in more generality - the best version I'm aware of is [here at Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035Q). The idea of the proof is the same, but in our case the assumption that $X,Y$ are integral saves a fair amount of technical hassle.